# Continuously change the position of range input element on mouse down event (in single steps)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I'm trying to build a slider using range input element which displaces by 1 step on click, scroll or long press(continuous press). I have the logic required for click and scroll, however the same logic doesn't seem to be working on mouse down event (for long/continuous press).

Here's my code so far (for click and mouse down) : https://jsfiddle.net/ykun1k13/

```js
var cur = 0;

d3.select('input')
  .on("input", function() {

    var threshold = d3.select(this).node().value;
    if (threshold > cur) {
      cur++
    } else if (threshold < cur) {
      cur--
    }
    d3.select(this).node().value = cur;

  });

d3.select('input')
  .on("mousedown", function() {
    var node1 = this;

    int = setInterval(function() {
      var threshold = d3.select(node1).node().value;
      if (threshold > cur) {
        cur++
      } else if (threshold < cur) {
        cur--
      }
      d3.select(node1).node().value = cur;
    }, 100)

  }).on('mouseup', function() {
    clearInterval(int);
  });
```

```css
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="25" step="1" value="0" orient="vertical">
</p>
```

I have added a mouse up event and setInterval to continuously track the mouse down in intervals of 100ms until user stops pressing the mouse.

It looks like the 'mouse down' is not working as 'input' event here and value of threshold is fetched not as the location of cursor but rather the current location of slider bar.

What might be the issue here? How can i make this work for continuous/long press?

Comment: When you define threshold again in the mousedown event it is returning the value of "cur" , because you are setting it as cur right above. Use a variable that sits outside the scope of the two for threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mousedown` and `mouseup` events are not supposed to continuously fire cause they are triggered only when the mouse is pressed or released.

There would be two timers, one for `mousedown` and another one for `changeValue()`, when `mousedown` time longer than 500ms, it would trigger a `changeTimer` calculating the value of the input base on the `isIncreasing`.
When `mouseup`, clear both timers.

```js
var mouseTimer,
    changeTimer,
    cur = 0,
    threshold = 0,
    isIncreasing = false;

d3.select('input')
  .on('input', function() {
    threshold = +this.value;
    if(+threshold > +cur) {
      cur++;
      isIncreasing = true;
    }
    else{
      cur--;
      isIncreasing = false;
    }
    this.value = cur;
  })

d3.select('input')
  .on("mousedown", function() {
    var input = this;
    ClearTimeout();
      mouseTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        changeValue(input);
      }, 500);
})

d3.select(window)
  .on('mouseup', function() {
    ClearTimeout();
  });

function changeValue(input){
  changeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
    if(isIncreasing){
      cur++;
      cur = cur > threshold ? threshold : cur;
    }
    else {
      cur--;
      cur = cur < threshold ? threshold : cur;
    }
    input.value = cur;
    changeValue(input);
  }, 100)
}

function ClearTimeout() {
  clearTimeout(mouseTimer);
  clearTimeout(changeTimer);
}
```

```css
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="25" step="1" value="0" orient="vertical">
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... however the above demo doesn't seem to be working in steps of 1 and pressing down just continuously displaces the slider to right (doesn't stop at threshold)

Comment: My apologize for misunderstanding your question, I hope this time I understand correctly. Please let me know if there's anything wrong.

Comment: Now it broke the normal functionality of the input range slider ... i.e. it doesn't work on normal clicks/drags/arrow keys (you can see that in my initial code) now which is probably because the code is overriding the normal input functions now

Comment: `input()` might be the issue. I'll check and come back later.

Comment: I update the snippet, which can click/ drag/ arrow key/ long press control now.